# Was there a Classical-era word for "lawyer" specifically?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, vocabulary

In the time of the late Republic, an *ōrātor* like Cicero would give all sorts of speeches. And some of his most famous are either attacking or defending someone on trial.

Was there a Classical-era word for someone who did this specifically, narrower than the general *ōrātor*? In other words, some equivalent to our modern "lawyer" (or even narrower "prosecutor" or "defense attorney" perhaps)?

Comment: *Advocatus* seems to cover at least a subset of this, but L&S are terse about it.

Comment: *Defensor* and *accusator* also quite literally mean "defense attorney" and "prosecutor," at least in the context of legal proceedings.

Answer (score 3):

Lewis & Short's *patronus* entry gives some options used by classic authors:

> **II. Transf.,** *a defender before a court of justice, an advocate,* pleader (syn.: advocatus, causidicus, procurator, cognitor): judicis est semper in causis verum sequi, patroni nonnumquam verisimile, etiamsi minus sit verum, defendere, Cic. Off. 2, 14, 51; id. de Or. 2, 69, 280: patronus alicui causae constitui, id. Mur. 2, 4; cf.: his de causis ego huic causae patronus exstiti, id. Rosc. Am. 2, 5; Lex. Servil. lin. 9: patronus partis adversae, Quint. 4, 1, 11; cf.: patronus adversarii, id. 4, 1, 11; Tac. Or. 1.